# Wifi option is not showing in kali linux

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, network-interface, networkmanager

I have a dual boot with windows and Kali-Linux.

after installing kali Linux, the Wifi option is not showing and also not able to connect to the internet.
so, not able to download any packages. after googling I also started network-manager.
Since I m new to this plateform. please help.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the result of the usual troubleshooting steps. If you don't know these, you probably should not use Kali. [See here](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a wifi dongle first make sure if it has linux support

But if you are using cable it must be your setting

Anyway if you are in need of internet right now I suggest you using the "usb tethering" you can share your smartphone internet to your computer using a charging cable with it